# Code description for \tl_if_empty:VTF

Tags: conditionals

Is the following code description correct ?

```
%% Test for empty Token List \feuds_teorema_parent_tl.

%% VTF are Type Specifers for the arguments to the function.

%% V  Indicates that first argument is a variable (a Token List
%%    Variable in this case). The variable is specified by its name
%%    without the backslash.

%% T  Indicates the code block to execute when test is true,
%%    when Token List Variable is empty.

%% F  Indicates the code block to execute when test is false,
%%    when Token List Variable is not empty.

\tl_if_empty:VTF \feuds_teorema_parent_tl
    %% IF CONDITION - Empty Parent, No Parent Counter
    {
      \tl_if_empty:VTF \feuds_teorema_shared_tl
          %% IF CONDITION Empty Code Block
          {
            \feuds_newteora_simple:VV
            \feuds_teorema_name_tl
            \feuds_teorema_label_tl
          }
        %% ELSE CONDITION
        {
          %% Shared Counter
          \feuds_newteorema_shared:VVV
          \feuds_teorema_name_tl
          \feuds_teorema_label_tl
          \feuds_teorema_shared_tl
        }
    }

  %% ELSE CONDITION Non-Empty Parent
  {
    %% Parent Counter
    \feuds_newteorema_parent:VVV
    \feuds_teorema_name_tl
    \feuds_teorema_label_tl
    \feuds_teorema_parent_tl
  }
```

Comment: yes, as documented in interface3 section 15.3

Comment: As are definitions of `V`, `T`, and `F` in comments ?

Comment: They are documented earlier, but they're in interface3, too, yes. Your commented definition of V is partly wrong. See section 1.1.

Comment: sorry I don't understand the question, `V`, `T`  are defined in "defining functions" section 4.3.1 (and section 1.1 Naming functions and variables)

Comment: @Veak oh V comment is wrong it needs the backslash, as you clearly show in the code. (as cfr notes)

Comment: The Token List Variable would be named `\feuds_teorema_parent_tl in this case.  Qk ?

Comment: @Veak No, variables should have a `l_` or `g_` prefix, denoting whether they should be assigned values locally or globally. In your case, `\l_feud_teorema_parent_tl`.